# How to pass and retrieve parameters from url in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

my url is

```
http://localhost/helpinghand_web/home/userAutologin?tval=Eo7TIhTJqQnfysn8mwu2nXOQ0yJvY36hprJ99GJH9NBZHTh1LU&page=profile
```

there are two parameter tval and page how can i get it.
following are not working..

```
$var=$_GET['tval'];
$var=$this->input->get('tval');
```

Comment: You can get the complete information about the same from the below give URL : https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html

Comment: are you getting any error ? if not then `$this->input->get('tval');` this should work.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
$tval = $this->input->get('tval');
$page = $this->input->get('page');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$params = $this->input->get(null, true);
```

to get all the params passed and then use:

```
$params['tval']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $tval = $this->input->get('tval') for get single data & $tval = $this->input->get() for get all date in singel variable in array format.

Answer (score 0):

```
 I managed the query you can use it.
```

If you call www.example.com?tval=1100, it will echo 1100, provided the Home

```
controller is routed correctly.

You can also use the http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%... to get these parameters.

For your query: $this->input->get('tval', TRUE);
```